# Magento Pager on product list

Tags: list, magento, product, pager

How do I insert only the pager in the bottom of product list?

At the top of the product list I want: "Sort by relevance/bestselers/etc" and the "Sort item by: Table/list", this I was able to do.

At the bottom of the product list I only want the pager, I've tried to insert the following code in list.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
```

but this php code doesn't work directly on the product list.

How can I make the pager work on the product list and appear at the bottom?

Comment: do you want two types of pager html one at the top with sort by features other in bottom only pager? am i correct

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 2):

Hello you create new toolbar-bottom.phtml file with following code
i.e  **app/design/frontend/(base or default)/(default or yourtheme)/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar-bottom.phtml**

```
<?php if ($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
    <div class="toolbar">
        <div class="pager"> 
            <p class="amount"> 
                <?php if ($this->getLastPageNum() > 1): ?> 
                    <?php echo $this->__('Items %s to %s of %s total', $this->getFirstNum(), $this->getLastNum(), $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
                <?php else: ?> 
                    <strong>
                        <?php echo $this->__('%s Item(s)', $this->getTotalNum()) ?>
                    </strong>
                <?php endif; ?> </p> 
            <div class="limiter"> 
                <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label> 
                <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)"> 
                    <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if ($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <?php echo $_limit ?> 
                    </option> 
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?> </div> <?php
        echo
        $this->getPagerHtml()
        ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php  endif ?>
```

call into  bottom of line in **app/design/frontend/(base or default)/(default or yourtheme)/template/catalog/product/list.phtml**

getToolbarBlock()->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar-bottom.phtml')->toHtml();

Comment: This idea helped me use specific items of the toolbar.

Comment: Thank you so much for this code 
Really helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can do this one of two ways.

1) Using CSS

```
<div class="category-products">
   <div class='top-toolbar'><?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?></div>

 ...
   <div class='bottom-toolbar'><?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?></div>
</div>
```

In css

```
 .bottom-toolbar .xyz{
    display:none;
 }
```

2) Using a Custom module to overwrite `getToolbarHtml` and

```
$this->getToolbarHtml('top-toolbar');

$this->getToolbarHtml('bottom-toolbar');


public function getToolbarHtml($toolbar_position)
{   
    $this->toolbar_position = $toolbar_position;
    return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
}
```

Then try to pass `$this->toolbar_position` to each block to show the section you need

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
$toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();
$toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection);
if($toolbar->getCollection()->getSize() > 0):
echo $toolbar->getPagerHtml(); //Pager
echo $toolbar-> __('Items %s to %s of %s total', $toolbar->getFirstNum(), $toolbar->getLastNum(),
$toolbar ->getTotalNum());
endif;
```

font:
http://mayankpatel104.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/magento-pagination-without-toolbar.html